# Create a new tab for each goto comment

Tags: vba, excel

I have a a spreadsheet with a lot of information. Each section of information has a comment that allows us to find it using the goto function (F5).

I would like to make a vba script/macro that loops through all the comments and puts the associated data into a new tab for each commented section.

I have searched and can't find any info on how to do this. If anyone can provide a link where something like this has been done I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please make an attempt at writing this code and share that attempt here.  You will find that the community is responsive to your efforts, I think.

Comment: I have no idea where to start, I don't need someone to write the code, just a link to some information would be appreciated.

Comment: Search for "excel VBA loop through cells" and "excel VBA cell comments" for ideas.  What you would first need to do is loop through the cells, then evaluate the comments for the search term.  Once you have the comments in the search term you can perform your search.  This is somewhat complex if you've never done VBA before.  If you're new to VBA I would recommend you search for how to record a macro.  This is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you n8 for the hints. I got something working, here it is:

```
Dim sheetName As String
```

sheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

```
Dim nName As Name

For Each nName In Names
    If InStr(1, nName.RefersTo, sheetName) > 0 Then
        Application.Goto Reference:=nName.Name
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = nName.Name
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
Next nName
```